# Gulp erases index.html contents

Tags: angularjs, html, gulp, jhipster

After searching for a straight answer on this issue and not finding it, I decide to open a debate here.

This is the problem: when reloading changes on the browser through `Gulp` on a web application generated with `JHipster` - on a number of times, it so happens that the `index.html` will empty partially or fully its contents, creating an obvious error on the browser.

It is not a huge issue, as I just keep a fresh copy of `index.html` and copy-paste it on the IDE when this does happen, but it would be nice to know if anyone else has suffered this issue and if there is a solution to it?

```
gulp.task('inject', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js').pipe(angularFilesort()), {relative: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));
});

gulp.task('wiredep', ['wiredep:test', 'wiredep:app']);

gulp.task('wiredep:app', function () {
    var stream = gulp.src(config.app + 'index.html')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(wiredep({
            exclude: [
                /angular-i18n/,  // localizations are loaded dynamically
                'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/' // Exclude Bootstrap js files as we use ui-bootstrap
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app));
```

Comment: "I decide to open a debate here" I remind you that this is a Q&A site, and should not be a room for debate. Also note that your issue may be related with how JHipster prepares the Gulp tasks of your project. Can you include the relevant parts of your "gulpfile.js" in your question?

Comment: Hi E_Net, thank you for your reply, first of all, I disagree with your input about debate

Debate: serious discussion of a subject in which many people take part (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/debate), if that's not what we do here...

  However, to the important things, I have edited my question and added all tasks that use index.html

Comment: We generally do not support discussion but some level of feedback with the use of comments (anything else should take place in chat). This isn't simply my opinion: the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) explicitly states that "If your motivation for asking the question is _“I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”_, then you should not be asking here."

Comment: Those gulp tasks seem to overwrite index.html for injecting the scripts, so there may be a short moment in which reloading your page will make the browser retrieve an incomplete page. If you wait until all building tasks are complete, is index.html in a consistent state?